# How to use Go Release Binary GitHub Action

Tags: go, github, release, github-actions

Anyone able to get [Go Release Binary GitHub Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/go-release-binary) working? which is supposed to

> Automate publishing Go build artifacts for GitHub releases through GitHub Actions

The readme looks rather simple, but I've tried all my imaginations to get it working but not avail. Similar questions has been asked in its issue tracks but got no answer.

Somebody help please.

BTW, while searching for the answer, I came upon [this commit logs](https://github.com/infraweavers/GoBuildTest/commits/main), which is quite interesting/amusing to read. I.e., it seems to be quite a battle to get it working, but the author gave up eventually (no any releases from his/her latest commits/tags)

**Conclusion:**

Turns out that my project does not have `go mod` and there were issues in Go Release which stops it from working. It was then fixed by [this](https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser/pull/2129) and [this](https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser/commit/50117da6b5adcabffe30adae9985450ba078b49a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually wrote my own [release workflow](https://github.com/jidicula/template-go/blob/57ddf441732bf905c893d547b9dc5efa2dc039a0/.github/workflows/release-draft.yml) for generating Go binaries.

The only non-obvious steps from my point of view are:

1. I have a release note generation step where I include a list of non-merge commits since the last release tag.
2. I use a matrix build for GOOS and GOARCH pairs and do some Bash string manipulation in the "Get OS and arch info" step.

The nice thing about `softprops/action-gh-release` is that you can keep adding artifacts to the same release as long as the workflow run is triggered by a push to the same tag.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/tags
    tags:
      - 'v*' # Push events to matching v*, i.e. v1.0, v20.15.10

name: Latest Release

defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash

jobs:
  lint:
    name: Lint files
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: '1.16.3'
      - name: golangci-lint
        uses: golangci/golangci-lint-action@v2.5.2
        with:
          version: latest
  test:
    name: Run tests
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'
    needs: lint
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: '1.16.3'
      - run: go test -v -cover
  release:
    name: Create Release
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'
    needs: test
    strategy:
      matrix:
        # List of GOOS and GOARCH pairs from `go tool dist list`
        goosarch:
          - 'aix/ppc64'
          # etc
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: '1.16.3'
      - name: Get OS and arch info
        run: |
          GOOSARCH=${{matrix.goosarch}}
          GOOS=${GOOSARCH%/*}
          GOARCH=${GOOSARCH#*/}
          BINARY_NAME=${{github.repository}}-$GOOS-$GOARCH
          echo "BINARY_NAME=$BINARY_NAME" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "GOOS=$GOOS" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "GOARCH=$GOARCH" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Build
        run: |
          go build -o "$BINARY_NAME" -v
      - name: Release Notes
        run:
          git log $(git describe HEAD~ --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --pretty='format:* %h %s%n  * %an <%ae>' --no-merges >> ".github/RELEASE-TEMPLATE.md"
      - name: Release with Notes
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        with:
          body_path: ".github/RELEASE-TEMPLATE.md"
          draft: true
          files: ${{env.BINARY_NAME}}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: There were issues in Go Release which stops it from working, but when I tried it today, everything is working now. Thanks for helping, so I'll accept your answer as the answer.